# SQL hierarchical table need to be simplified

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, hierarchy

I'm having a little trouble on making my table a bit more simple, let me explain:

Table structure with input:

```
OLD_KEY | NEW KEY
  4536     4566
  4566     4977
  4321     10290
  5423     8920
```

I'm getting data from a source, that is changing retro my PK(serial number) in a few tables; and after that, I need to update all those table to their new serial number.

My problem is, instead of a simple update, the data can come like in the example, and change twice or more for the same old key like(in the example) 4536 first changes to 4566 and then changes again to 4977.

This is currently forcing me to use a cursor, which will update each table row by row ordered by the first key and ETC...

It used to be just fine, but lately, the data amount multiplied it self by a lot and making this process very heavy and taking a lot of resources.

My question is: I need to eliminate all those keys that have to be updated twice or more, to just once, meaning - out put like this for the above example:

```
OLD_KEY | NEW_KEY
  4536     4977
  4321     10290
  5423     8920
```

Thought about using hierarchical functions with prior and start with.. but where do I start with?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( old_key ) AS old_key,
       new_key
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH old_key NOT IN ( SELECT new_key FROM table_name )
CONNECT BY PRIOR new_key = old_key;
```

Comment: Was just in the middle of writing it myself:) thx , work perfect.

Comment: Can you have more than one change on the same old value? for example 1->2; 3->1; 1->4